# How to allow only 15 digits with the slash bot discord command? in python

Tags: python, discord

How to allow only 15 digits with the slash bot discord command? in python

I'm trying to program a bot for discord that allows you to delete an imgur image with the deletehash , what I'm trying to do is that it can only allow 15 digits since the deletehash has 15 digits, but when adding less than 15 digits it throws me error in the console (CMD)

This is the error it shows me:

```
An exception has occurred while executing command `borrar1`:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\iroke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord_slash\client.py", line 1352, in invoke_command
        await func.invoke(ctx, **args)
      File "C:\Users\iroke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord_slash\model.py", line 210, in invoke
        return await self.func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\xampp\htdocs\imgur\imgur\img\cu.py", line 31, in borrar1
        while len(borrar_imagen)  !=15:
    TypeError: object of type 'SlashMessage' has no len()
```

This is the code I'm using:

```
 import discord
    from discord.ext import commands
    from discord_slash import SlashCommand
    from discord_slash.utils.manage_commands import create_choice, create_option
    from discord_slash import SlashCommand, SlashContext
    import requests
    
        bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '/')
        bot.remove_command("help") # Borra el comando por defecto !help
        slash = SlashCommand(bot, sync_commands=True)
        @slash.slash(
            name="borrar1", description="Escribe La id para borrar la iamgen",
            options=[
                        create_option(
                          name="borrar_imagen",
                          description="Escribe el ID para borrar la imagen",
                          option_type=3,
                          required=True
                        ),
                         
            ])
                          
                    
                     
        
            
        
        
        async def borrar1(ctx:SlashContext, borrar_imagen:str):
            url = f"https://api.imgur.com/3/image/{borrar_imagen}"
            while len(borrar_imagen) !=15:
                borrar_imagen = await ctx.send("Sólo 15 digitos")
            payload={}
            files={}
            
            headers = {
                'Authorization': "Bearer "}
            response = requests.request("DELETE", url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)
        
            embed=discord.Embed(title="", description="Imagen borrada con exito!", color=0x00ff11)
            if response.json()["status"] == 200:
                    await ctx.send(embed=embed, hidden=True)
        
            embed=discord.Embed(title="", description="No está permitido paginas webs", color=0xff0019)        
            if response.json()["status"] == 400:
                await ctx.send(embed=embed, hidden=True)  
        
            embed=discord.Embed(title="", description="Error!", color=0xff0019)   
            if response.json()["status"] == 403:
                await ctx.send(embed=embed, hidden=True) 
    
    bot.run("")
```

This is the part that is failing:

```
while len(borrar_imagen) !=15:
            borrar_imagen = await ctx.send("Sólo 15 digitos")
```

I don't know how to fix it

Could someone help me, thank you very much!

Comment: str(borrar_imagen) maybe?

Comment: Wait a second: why are you using while? Does it get fixed with "if"?

Comment: If necessary, just return from the function.

Comment: Yes I tried it, and the bot spams all the time, and sometimes it says that the imgur image was successfully deleted! i.imgur.com/MlCBkNf.png i.imgur.com/AR8Pe4t.png

Comment: Ok, so if a problem is detected: return to exit the function.

Comment: I left the function, but when writing the correct 15 digits it does not delete the image